# Statusbar turns back visible after screenshot or power menu

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, callback, statusbar

I have an activity with this theme:

pre-v21:

```
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

v21:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

And in the activity I'm doing the following to hide the status bar:

```
val decorView = window.decorView
val uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
```

The problem is that when the user performs a system action: Screenshot, PowerMenu or Recents the status bar is shown. I've managed the Recents with hiding the status in `onResume()` which unfortunately isn't called after a screenshot is taken or after the power menu is shown.

Any idea of which callback I need to use to force the status bar mode in invisible?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that `onWindowFocusChanged` is being called after these 2 scenarios. It's actually being called way more times, but, checking the `hasFocus` parameter I can hide or not the status bar as I wanted.

Can this be added in some documentation? :D